# How can be created an independent directory for each user in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, directory

I'm building a shiny app that create multiple files depending on the uploade file by the user. The created files has the same names and this can make that when a user download the files end with a none relative information to his data.

**How can be created an independent directory for each user in Shiny app?**

I have found the next solution so far to create the directory to store the files:

```r
directory <- paste0(format(Sys.time(),"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),rnorm(1),
                    rnorm(1))
dir.create(directory)
setwd(directory)
```

But I have read that this may not work if I upload the app to a server. **How should I do it?**

Comment: Your last comment is right -- this probably depends on how you are going to deploy the app (e.g., shinyapps.io, or your own Shiny Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-create-a-working-directory-for-each-user-in-shiny-app/80067/2?u=david31021) is the answer that I get in RStudio community and worked for me:

By @pieterjanvc from RStudio community:

> Setting the working directory is likely not going to work like that in Shiny. I suggest you generate a folder based off the user's session token, which is generated when a user connects to a Shiny app and located in the session variable.

```r
library(shiny)
    
ui <- fluidPage(
    
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
     
   dir.create(session$token)
   file.create(paste0(session$token, "/userFile.txt"))
     
}
    
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

> Once you created the directory, you can save any file in that one using again the token which is the name of the base folder for that user. You should remember to erase the folder after the task finished, or you will have a lot of folders soon.